# Ionic Drop Down Selected Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, ionic-framework

This is my drop down menu code :

```
<label id="labelPersonalInformationExtra" class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
  <span id="inputLabel" class="input-label">Gender</span>
  <select id="dropDownPersonalDetails"  ng-options="gender.name for gender in genders"  ng-model="gender" ng-change="updateGender(gender)"  >
    <option  ng-selected="true">{{genderPlaceholder}}</option>
  </select>
</label>
```

The json that fills the drop down looks like this :

```
{"0":"Select gender","1":"Male","2":"Female"}
```

The gender placeholder is the previously selected gender.But when I create the drop down, it ends up looking like this:

```
 - Female 
 - Female
 - Male
```

instead of

```
 - Female
 - Male
```

Comment: include all related code to OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the below code it will solve your problem.

```
 <select id="dropDownPersonalDetails" ng-options="gender.name for gender in  genders" ng-model="gender" ng-change="updateGender(gender)">
  <option  class="option-bg" value="" disabled>Select your Gender</option>
 </select>
```

Comment: but i need to put the genderPlaceholder in. And if i place 'select your gender' the information would double.

Comment: please use the above code as it is it will work .Please check your code once